# How much energy one would get by tethering an imaginary rope to a galaxy and let it unwind until reaching the Hubble horizon?

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, energy, cosmology, space-expansion

Based on the tethered galaxies gedankenexperiment [1](https://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1995ApJ...446...63H), let's imagine we attach an imaginary cosmologically-long string to a galaxy that is at a sufficiently long distance to be drawn away by the Hubble flow.

In an accelerating universe (like our own), there would be always tension to the string and that tension is used to make energy (as it is indicated in [1](https://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1995ApJ...446...63H)). We let the string unwind as the galaxy recedes until reaching the Hubble horizon, where the string would break.

My question is: How much energy would we harness with this? Would it be equal to the energy corresponding to the rest mass of the galaxy (given by the famous equation E=mc²)? Or would it be less or greater than that?

Answer (score 2):

A simple argument in a de Sitter background gives an extracted energy of $mc^2$.

The usual static coordinates for de Sitter space are

$$ds^2 = \left(1-\frac{r^2}{R^2}\right)dt^2 - \left(1-\frac{r^2}{R^2}\right)^{-1}dr^2 - r^2 dΩ^2$$

The event horizon is at $r=R$. The angular coordinates are irrelevant to this problem so I'll drop them.

In a manifold with metric $ds^2 = f(r)^2 dt^2 - f(r)^{-2} dr^2$, the proper acceleration of a worldline at constant $r$ is $f'(r)$ inward. The work done on a slow-moving test object of small mass moving from $r$ to $r+dr$ is the mass times the acceleration times the metric distance moved, i.e., $-m\,f'(r)\,f(r)^{-1}\,dr$. However, if you transmit this energy to $r_0$, due to gravitational redshift it is reduced by a factor of $f(r)/f(r_0)$ when it arrives. The total extractable energy is therefore

$$-\frac{m}{f(r_0)} \int_{r_i}^{r_f} f'(r)\,dr = m\frac{f(r_i)-f(r_f)}{f(r_0)}$$

If $r_i=r_0$ (lowering from your location) and $f(r_f)=0$ (lowering to an event horizon), then the extracted energy is $m(c^2)$.

This argument is independent of $f$, and works with other metrics that have this form, such as Schwarzschild, Reissner-Nordström, and Schwarzschild-de Sitter black holes.

Comment: Thank you. So, even taking into account the effects of redshifting, the harnessed energy would be equal to mc²? @benrg

Comment: @vengaq By this simple/simplistic argument, yes, it's $mc^2$ with redshift taken into account.

Comment: Would this also apply to stars? I mean, due to the nature of fusion reactions, stars lose parts of their mass (converted into energy) as they "burn their fuel". So if we did this mental experiment with a receding star, after reaching the Hubble horizon, would we still get an energy of 2? That is, could we "make" a new star with the same mass that it initially had? @benrg

Comment: @vengaq With the usual caveat that this is very unrealistic, yes. If you start with a star of mass $m$ and lower it (over a short time compared to its lifetime) until you've extracted $\frac12mc^2$ energy from the lowering, the locally measured mass of the star is still $m$ but there's a redshift factor of $2$ between it and you. If you let it shine there until half its mass is converted to light, you only get $\frac14mc^2$ because of redshifting. The locally measured mass of the star is then $\frac12m$, but when you lower it the rest of the way, you get $\frac14mc^2$. In all you get $mc^2$.

Comment: Mmmh...But I meant whether one could get the full mc2 just by the unwinding string mechanism (by "lowering" the star). I mean, if we assume that the mass that the star transforms into light is lost forever into space (and we don't recover that light), could we still get mc2 only by lowering the star up until the horizon? @benrg

Comment: @vengaq No, if the mass is lost then it's lost. It's the same as if the star broke into two pieces and you lowered only one.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that galaxy is in distance L from us. The average velocity of this Galaxy can be explained by the initial universe expanding and is equal:
$$v\sim HL\Rightarrow W_{kin}= M_{galaxy}v^2/2\approx M_{galaxy}H^2L^2/2$$
Considering the probable infinite accelerating of expanding (we cannot be sure in it), we can calculate the inertial forces that can experience object in the distance L from us. Let's set the easiest relation $H=H_0+kt$ (really $\dot{H}=-H^2(1+q)$ but we don't know q), because the times of major change in function are very big. So a=kL and we'll get energy (from relativistic 2nd newton law):
$$F=M_{galaxy}(a\gamma +(v^2/c^2)\gamma^{3}a)=kLM_{galaxy}\gamma(1 +(v^2/c^2)\gamma^2)=_{(v=HL)}=kM_{galaxy}L\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+H^2L^2/c^2}}(1 +\dfrac{H^2L^2}{c^2+H^2L^2})$$
This is not conservative force so the energy will depend on how are you pulling your rope. But if we will just integrate this force we will get:
$$W_{in_1}\approx \int_0^{F(v=c)}FdL=\dfrac{kM_{galaxy}c^2}{H^2} (-3 + 2.5\sqrt{2})$$
In some models Hubble constant decreases with time (k<0) but each galaxy will still accelerating because will also experience inertial force, associated with changing inertial system of body due to moving from us (just like coriolis force):
$$a_{in_2}=Hv_{radial}\approx H^2L\Rightarrow F=H^2LM_{galaxy}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+H^2L^2/c^2}}(1 +\dfrac{H^2L^2}{c^2+H^2L^2})$$
This is also not conservative force so the energy will depend on how are you pulling your rope. But if we will just integrate this force we will get:
$$W_{in_2}\approx \int_0^{F(v=c)}FdL=M_{galaxy}c^2 (-3 + 2.5\sqrt{2})$$
Too simplify calculations I assumed that initial L is much smaller than $L_{HubHor}$. Also we can see factors like $mc^2$.

Let's also consider gravitational forces that in our model assumed weaker than influence of dark matter. Average density of universe is approximately $10^{-26}kg/m^3$, so the gravitational force will depend linearly from distance:
$$F=\dfrac{M_{galaxy}G\rho L^3}{L^2}\Rightarrow W_{grav}=-M_{galaxy}G\rho(L_{HubHor}^2-L^2)/2$$
That's the simpliest calculations that we can make for you question. For any clarifications you need to refer to specific models like Friedmann universe and manipulating with maximum of non-conservative force's work.

Comment: What does "Considering the probable infinite accelerating of expanding (we cannot be sure in it)" mean? Are you assuming the expansion is a dragging effect that can do infinite work? If that were true (it isn't), how would clumping happen? What does "For any clarifications you need to refer to specific models like Friedmann universe" mean? What are you assuming, if not a Friedmann universe?

Comment: I didn't write that anything can do infinite work. I just said that future of Hubble constant is different for different deceleration parameter q in law:
$$\dot{H}=-H^2(1+q)$$