# Power density of free space under expansion

Tags: general-relativity, space-expansion, perpetual-motion

Back when I owned a consulting business, I had to occasionally refuse attempts to engage me to help someone complete "just a detail or two" on their perpetual motion machine.

Usually I tried to do this politely, by explaining that no way, no how, was a perpetual motion machine going to work, because there's this thing called conservation of energy.

But -- thanks to Emily Noether and universal expansion, energy *isn't* conserved.  It's conserved for all practical purposes, but -- it isn't *really* conserved on cosmological scales.

My question is -- how much energy is generated by the expansion of space in your average cubic meter (or, perhaps, your average galaxy)*?  I'm sure the number is ridiculously small, but I'm looking for some concrete analogy, like "the expansion of space in the <*insert cosmological object here*> is the same as one burning candle".

Does it take a solar-system sized space to power a candle?  A globular cluster?  Our galaxy?  Alternatively, how much power is generated by the expansion of space in a region the size of our solar system, or our galaxy, or whatever?

---

* I'm aware that in expansion-of-space terms there may not be an "average" cubic meter -- I'm open to being educated on this point, too, unless there's a handy way to gloss over it.

Comment: See [How much energy one would get by tethering an imaginary rope to a galaxy and let it unwind until reaching the Hubble horizon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/727622/180843)